# Query Designed to only return results with dates before today (SQL Lite)

Tags: sqlite, date

Attempting to only query results that had DateDue values that took place before today, no matter what 'today' is. The three records have DateDue values of "04/09/17", "05/15/2017" and "07/18/2017". Ideally, only one record would return as 04/09/17 is the only date in the past in the table. Currently all three records are returning and none return if I query 'DateDue > date('now').

```
SELECT FName, LName, DateDue
FROM JOB, CLIENT
WHERE JOB.JClientID = CLIENT.ClientID AND
DateDue < date('now')
Order by DateDue
```

Comment: is DueDate a date field? or is it a text?

Comment: It's a date field

Comment: try using DATE(NOW()) instead of date(now)

Comment: didn't change anything

Comment: SELECT FName, LName, DateDue
FROM JOB inner join CLIENT
ON JOB.JClientID = CLIENT.ClientID WHERE
DateDue < DATE(NOW())
Order by DateDue

Comment: Still doesnt work, I noticed that the 'DateDue' function is formatted mm/dd/yyyy,while date('now') is yyyy-mm-dd. Could this be impacting the inequality query?

Comment: what do you mean by duedate function. is it a function? how come?

Comment: DateDue is a DATE type field that holds three dates total.